# How to model a dress shirt collar such as the one found in zootopia?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

How would I go about modeling a shirt collar similar to the one worn by Nick Wilde in the movie "zootopia".

[image]

I just cant seem to get it right even though it doesn't  seem that hard. I'm planning on using a cloth simulation so the shape doesn't need to be exact.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the following topology works, tell me if it's ok (I used a *Solidify* modifier at the end to give it thickness):

[image]