# How people usually would do clothing?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I'm having a problem with creating clothes. The main problem is that I cant understand how to make a good looking on mesh collar on a shirt for example, or for another example the beginning of sleeves. Other than those parts everything looks fine. I have an idea to use boolean or shrinkwrap but not sure it will not create other vertices I don't need.

Comment: it really depends on the style you want to achieve, is it realistic? cartoony? etc... generally you will give thickness to your shirt but you can do it at the end with a Solidify modifier...

Comment: I'd say the style more of cartoony than realistic but it doesn't really matter I think. Again the problem is the holes where the character's limbs should go out, like a collar. I don't know how to make those holes that will look natural on the mesh. My guess is that people use the knife or shrinkwrap to do them.

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137530/how-to-model-a-dress-shirt-collar-such-as-the-one-found-in-zootopia

Comment: I'm trying to replicate more complex mesh than this. Here's how its looks like http://prntscr.com/u924w0

Comment: you'll easily find tutorial about how to model low-poly characters with clothes, from there you just need to add details, for example in Sculpt mode, and bake later on

Comment: Actually I think you may just show me a new way of modeling. I thought you could bake only textures. But now I guess you can also bake things from Sculpt mode into the simpler mesh. I was always thinking that Sculpt mode was made just for art models that have too many vertices. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You can prepare a rather low-poly shirt, duplicate it to make a high-poly version, sculpt as much as you want, then bake the normals on the low-poly   ;)   plus there is a new tool in Sculput mode called Cloth that is dedicated to this kind of work